# Permesso is not ready and student visa is expired

Tags: visas, us-citizens, italian-residents

I studied for one year in Italy and my student visa is now expired. I applied for my permesso but due to some lost documents at the questura it wasnt ready for pickup until after I left for holidays in the US. Now I am planning to fly back to Italy to reapply for another year to study but I don't have a visa and my permesso is in Italy. I also lost the post office receipt "bolletino" but I have a copy of the receipt that I paid. I also have a copy of the online form that allows you to track your permesso progress so I have a copy of that saying that the permesso is ready for pick up at the questura this month.

If anyone can help me and let me know if I will be able to get through at the airport that would be great as I am kinda nervous because I have some exams I still need to take at the end of this month.

Comment: What is your nationality? Some nationalities can enter the Schengen area for a short visit visa-free. If you can't do that you will probably have trouble boarding the aircraft without your documents.

Comment: I am a U.S citizen

Comment: You should be fine to enter and pick it up as long as your 90 visa-free days are available!

Answer (score 5):

[As a US citizen you can enter the Schengen area without needing a visa.](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Italy.html) You can then stay for 90 days. Therefore, my suggestion is that you use this visa-free access to enter Italy, and deal with the bureaucracy from there. In the meantime, prepare your case defense properly:

- Make sure your passport has at least six months of validity from your date of arrival in Italy
- Print out the application confirmation and the page that says your permit is ready for pickup
- Go to the police station and declare that you lost the *ricevuta*

You will need to bring all the supportive evidence you have in order to explain your situation to the immigration officer upon landing in Italy.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I also figured that I have the 90 days but at the questura they tried to tell me that the 90 days visa free goes into my student visa so they tried to tell me that i had already used that 90 days up while on my student visa which made no sense. Thank you again for the reply I really appreciate it!